# Does Conan support non-compiled packages?

Tags: conan

I have a group of class files which are shared by several of our projects.   We would like to start refactoring these classes, so I am starting by building a Conan package to allow us to version them.  The sticky part is that they do not build on their own; there is coupling both ways between the shared classes and the consuming classes.

As such, I've been trying to build a Conan package which simply includes the .h & .cpp files but does not attempt to build them.  My conanfile.py looks like this:

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake
import os

class SharedcodeConan(ConanFile):
    name = "SharedCode"
    version = "1.0"
    author = "me myemail"
    description = ""
    generators = "cmake", "visual_studio"
    exports_sources = "*"

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

    def package(self):
        self.copy("*.h", dst="include")
        self.copy("*.cpp", dst="src")
        self.copy("*.rc", dst="src")

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.includedirs = ['include']
```

This all works well.  I can create the package (specifying `--test-folder=None`).  When I pull it down from Artifactory, the include & src folders contain the files I expect.

What I cannot figure is how to bring the .cpp files into my Visual Studio project.  The Conan VS extension conveniently adds Visual Studio macros for the includes, linker, etc., but not for the source files.  As such, my project finds the header files, but linking fails.  In looking through the docs & the Conan source, I haven't seen an indication that this is currently possible.

**Is there a way to dynamically reference the src folder?**

*Update: In light of the comments below stating this isn't supported currently, any workaround ideas are also welcome.*

Comment: There is no access to your src folder, because is not a normal approach. You will need to ask it as a feature request: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-vs-extension/issues

Comment: @uilianries Thank you for the info!  I feared that might be the case.